# carousel overlaps to fixed nav bar when view is changed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, navbar

My HTML is this:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" >
      some divs inside... 
 </div>

 <div class="filler"> </div>

 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">  
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     </ol>

     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="<?php print(base_url('assets/images/slide-one.jpg')); ?>" alt="First slide" />
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <div class="main-text">TEXT 1!</div>
              <div class="sub-text">subtext</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="<?php print(base_url('assets/images/slide-two.jpg')); ?>" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <div class="main-text">TEXT 2</div>
              <div class="sub-text">subtext </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a> 
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.filler {
    height: 230px; //same height of class navbar.i do this so
                     carousel will not overlap the fixed navbar 
}
```

The design runs OK. The top div is fixed at the top. But when I change the view to smaller or to mobile view, the carousel overlaps the fixed navbar. How will I format my css so that carousel will not overlap? Or is there another way to format this? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of dropping relevant code with `carousel codes inside...`, post here the relevant information and create [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)